# Run a test using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie to selenium web driver.I have a test written in java which is to be tested using Selenium web driver. I ran the test class as a java application.I wrote the following snippet of code to obtain the instance of the ChromeDriver. I get the following message for the following code snippet.

```
    @Override
    public WebDriver get() {
        log.info("Creating Chrome driver");
        try {
            return new ChromeDriver(buildCapabilities());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
```

Also have the path to the ChromeDriver set

> private static final String CHROME_DRIVER = "chromedriver.exe";
>    URL chromeDriverUrl = getClass().getResource("/" + CHROME_DRIVER);
>    String pathToChromeDriver = chromeDriverUrl.getPath();
>    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToChromeDriver);

IMAGE:
[image]

Do not understand as to why the following message is displayed on the return new ChromeDriver(buildCapabilities()) line of code.

Answer (score 1):

to use chrome driver you need to download chrome driver from [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)

and then use the chrome driver by

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/Hussain/Desktop/selenium-2.30.0/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: @Sanika Joshi : I hope it serves you problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, ChromeDriver (and FireFox driver) are both RemoteWebDrivers, not WebDrivers.  Those types are not compatible.  As for why you're getting a firefox driver instead of a chrome one, I'm guessing that your either your buildCapabilities() function or your remote grid is returning a firefox driver.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple change. Reimporting my project into the IntelliJ evironment fixed the problem.
[image: Reimport symbol in Intellij]

Answer (score 0):

you may also try using  bonigarcia

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
  private WebDriver webDriver;

     public WebDriver getDriver(){
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*", "ignore-certificate-errors");
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        return webDriver;
    }
```